# Mimic C#'s nameof() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, reflection, scope

I rewrote some code I posted earlier this month. It attempts to mimic [C#'s `nameof()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695900/what-is-the-purpose-of-nameof) by extracting names from bytecode instructions.

This seems more reliable than looking into the previous frame's locals and asserting that there is an id match between some value in the current scope. However, I'm unsure just how much because it uses `dis`:

> Use of this module should not be considered to work across Python VMs
>   or Python releases.

I tried reducing the amount of bad input possible, but there is a quirky case where if I pass the function `name_of((Cls.member(), var))` it returns `'member'`, if I remove the parentheses it will raise a `SyntaxError` because it no longer mistakes them for the end of the function call, and attribute access has been broken, so what the hell does it make of `var`.

```
import dis as _dis
from itertools import dropwhile as _dropwhile, takewhile as _takewhile

__all__ = ['name_of']

_LOAD = (
    'LOAD_CONST',
    'LOAD_NAME',
    'LOAD_ATTR',
    'LOAD_GLOBAL',
    'LOAD_FAST',
    'LOAD_CLOSURE',
    'LOAD_DEREF',
    'LOAD_CLASSDEREF'
)


class _Scopes:
    known = {}


def _dis_f(frame):
    return iter(_dis.Bytecode(frame.f_code))


def _known():
    def scope():
        return scope.cached[scope.no]

    scope.cached = []
    scope.no = 0
    return scope


def _not_eq(instruction):
    return instruction.argrepr != 'name_of'


def _in_load(instruction):
    return instruction.opname in _LOAD


def _invalidate(name):
    _Scopes.known.clear()
    raise SyntaxError('Invalid: {!r}'.format(name))


def _is_ident(name):
    if not name.isidentifier():
        _invalidate(name)


def _eq(instruction):
    return instruction.opname == _LOAD[2]


def _all_attr(instructions, name):
    if instructions[:-1] and not all(
            _eq(instruction) for instruction in instructions[1:]
    ):
        _invalidate(name)


def _cache(bytecode, scope):
    while True:
        instructions = _dropwhile(_not_eq, bytecode)
        if next(instructions, None) is None:
            break
        instructions = list(_takewhile(_in_load, instructions))
        name = instructions[-1].argrepr
        _is_ident(name)
        _all_attr(instructions, name)
        scope.cached.append(name)


def _pos(frame_id, scope):
    scope.no += 1
    if scope.no == len(scope.cached):
        del _Scopes.known[frame_id]


def name_of(_):
    try:
        raise NameError
    except Exception as exc:
        frame = exc.__traceback__.tb_frame.f_back
    frame_id = id(frame)
    if frame_id not in _Scopes.known:
        bytecode = _dis_f(frame)
        scope = _Scopes.known[frame_id] = _known()
        _cache(bytecode, scope)
    else:
        scope = _Scopes.known[frame_id]
    name = scope()
    _pos(frame_id, scope)
    return name
```

Overall it seems to work as intended, in both 3.4.4 and 3.6.3.

Comment: I just wrote my own implementation of this: https://github.com/alexmojaki/nameof

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, however your code is *really* hard to understand.

- You merge your functions together better.

  `name_of` finds the parent frame, and then also goes on to handle creating and caching scope, along with finding the next name. This is defiantly breaking single responsibility.

  I'd also merge all your one/two line functions into `_cache`. This is so we can tell what your code is actually doing.

  What I'd do use:

  - the class for `_Scopes`,
  - a `_scope` function to build the scope,
  - a `_get_frame` function to get the current frame, and
  - the `name_of` function, to use `_get_frame`, and then call `_Scopes`.
- To create `_get_frame` I'd move the `try` into it's own function.
- To create `_scope` I'd:

  - Merge most of your code into `_cache`.
  - I manually perform the `dropwhile` and `takewhile` loops.
  - Move the code from `_is_ident` and `_all_attr` into the function.
  - Merge `_all_attr` with the `takewhile` loop. This is as you `raise` if `i.opname in _LOAD`. Unless it's LOAD_ATTR.
  - Remove the `instructions` list. It's not needed with the above, and you only want the last value anyway.
  - Don't mutate `_Scopes` from here.
  - Make this a generator of names, don't mutate anything.
- To create `_Scopes` I'd:

  - Create a class, that inherits from `collections.UserDict`.
  - Move the rest of your `name_of` code into a `next_name` method.
  - You also can change the code so that it's better too.

    - Get the scope by using `self.get`. This means if it's not `None` then you can return without a second look-up.
    - Try to get the `next(scope, None)` if it's none, then you can implicitly remove the scope, by falling through to the creating code. Otherwise you can return the name.
    - If you wrap the call to `_scope` in a `try`, then you can perform the `_Scopes.clear()` function in the `except` clause.

And so I'd change your code to (untested):

```
import dis as _dis
from collections import UserDict

__all__ = ['name_of']

_ATTR = 'LOAD_ATTR'
_LOAD = set(
    'LOAD_CONST',
    'LOAD_NAME',
    'LOAD_GLOBAL',
    'LOAD_FAST',
    'LOAD_CLOSURE',
    'LOAD_DEREF',
    'LOAD_CLASSDEREF'
)


def _scope(frame):
    bytecode = iter(_dis.Bytecode(frame.f_code))
    while True:
        for instruction in bytecode:
            if instruction == 'name_of':
                break
        else:
            break

        name = None
        for instruction in bytecode:
            if instruction.opname != _ATTR:
                if instruction.opname not in _LOAD:
                    break
                raise SyntaxError('Invalid: {!r}'.format(name))
            name = instruction

        if name is None or not name.argrepr.isidentifier():
            raise SyntaxError('Invalid: {!r}'.format(name))
        yield name.argrepr


class _Scopes(UserDict):
    def next_name(self, frame):
        frame_id = id(frame)
        scope = self.get(frame_id, None)
        if scope is not None:
            name = next(scope, None)
            if name is not None:
                return name
        try:
            scope = self.data[frame_id] = _scope(frame)
        except SyntaxError:
            self.clear()
            raise
        return next(scope)


_scopes = _Scopes()


def _get_frame():
    try:
        raise Exception
    except Exception as e:
        return exc.__traceback__.tb_frame.f_back


def name_of(_):
    frame = _get_frame().f_back
    return _scopes.next_name(frame)
```